# Correctly change SVG line coordinate using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, attr, jquery-svg

I'm trying to change one of the Y-coordinates of an SVG line, I'm using jQuery and the SVG plugin + animation plugin. I have been animating the lines previously, but here the function needs to simply change the position,

this works;

```
$(strings[i]).animate({ 
   svgY1 : 150
}, 0);
```

this does not;

```
$(strings[i]).attr( 
   'svgY1', '150'
);
```

I can see I **shouldn't** be using animate here, but I don't know why attr or css don't work in this context? I figure the problem is that svgY1 isn't the correct way to identify that coordinate maybe but I'm stuck.

At this point all concerned elements are static, I'm pretty sure it's not interference from another function.

Answer (score 2):

First, give the lines unique identifiers:

```
svg.line(g, 450, 120, 550, 20, {strokeWidth: 5, id: '123'});
```

Now use the change function of the svg manager:

```
svg.change(svg.getElementById('123'), { y1: 150 });
```

Comment: This looks like it should work, I'm on a different project right now, but unique ID's ought to be perfect, thanks!